# AWS CDK: How can I deploy multiple stack from a single stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Is it possible or any way around to deploy multiple stack from a single stack? For example, I define three stacks namely `DynamoDBStack`, `IAMRoleStack` and `LambdaStack`, now I want these stacks to be deployed under, lets say `DeployAllStacks`, so that it's identified as single stack in AWS CloudFormation stack list? I realised the following approach is wrong and `cdk ls` recognise as 4 stacks instead of one, I'm trying something like this:

```
public DeployAllStacks(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null):base(scope,id, props)
{
   new DynamoDBStack(this, "DataBase");
   new IAMRoleStack(this, "IAMRole");
   new LambdaStack(this, "Lambda")
}
```

I understand that if I write all the resources in one single stack then it's doable, however I want the code to be neater and write separate stack to reused elsewhere.

Comment: The CDK approach is to compose [multiple stacks in an App Construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html).  The stacks are deployed together as a group wih `cdk deploy --all`.  What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this too, however, this approach still shows up as two different stacks in CloudFormation stack list or `cdk ls`. How can we deploy all the stack from a single stack and identified as a single stack with `cdk ls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  Stacks are [the unit of deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html) in the CDK.  They can be grouped, but deploy separately in the cloud.

No matter. If code reuse is your goal, [construct subclasses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_author) are the idiomatic CDK approach to composition.  This is how the CDK itself is built.  Multi-stack Apps also have a role for bigger projects, although this adds friction to deploys and cross-stack references<sup>*</sup>.  See the CDK best practices guidance on [Constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-constructs) and [Stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-separate) for design considerations.  If I am interpreting your stack names correctly, one stack seems a good option, with construct subclasses for code org/reuse if needed.

---

* The CDK also [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.NestedStack.html) CloudFormation [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html), which is a non-CDK native approach to reuse.  But the child stacks are still stacks that "show up in the list".

Comment: Thanks fedovan for the detailed explanation. I shall try hands on construct subclass.